# Using Command Line Parameters with pytest --pyargs

Tags: python, pytest

I have written pytest unit tests for a package I've written with a structure like below:

- packagedir

  - setup.py
  - mypackage

    - __init__.py
    - functionpackage

      - __init__.py
      - functionmodule.py
    - test

      - __init__.py
      - conftest.py
      - unit_tests

        - __init__.py
        - functionmodule_test.py

Now packagedir/mypackage/test/conftest.py establishes two required command line parameters to be created as fixtures for the tests. When I run something like:

```
pytest packagedir/mypackage/ --var1 foo --var2 bar
```

All the tests run and the command line parameters are read in correctly. However, when I pip install the package (which installs the test and unit_tests packages correctly) and then try something like this:

```
pytest --pyargs mypackage --var1 foo --var2 bar
```

I get an error like this:

```
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --var1 foo --var2 bar
```

If I run:

```
pytest --pyargs mypackage
```

the tests run but fail because the command line arguments are not present.

Can someone explain to me what might be going wrong here? I could guess and say this is because the --pyargs argument changes the interpretation of the command line parameters for pytest, but it's just a guess. I'd like to know if there is an actual way I could fix this.

**The overarching goal would be to allow someone to pip install mypackage and then be able to easily test it without navigating to the site-packages location of the install.**

Comment: cross-referencing relevant pytest issue: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1596

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added a `__main__.py` to the `mypackage/test` directory and wrote

```
import os
import sys

HERE = os.path.dirname(__file__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pytest
    errcode = pytest.main([HERE] + sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(errcode)
```

Now, I can execute the tests with

```
python -m mypackage.test --myoption=works
```

This works when the package is installed.

You can view this in action with a travis build:

- [`__main__.py`](https://github.com/schul-cloud/schul_cloud_ressources_server_tests/blob/b246877f1880d1491ff3ad4be4ec58d6414c153a/schul_cloud_ressources_server_tests/tests/__main__.py)
- [Travis invocation](https://github.com/schul-cloud/schul_cloud_ressources_server_tests/blob/240aa5b5009f797822e69e86d0df1800591fdea8/.travis.yml#L14)
- [Travis output](https://travis-ci.org/schul-cloud/schul_cloud_ressources_server_tests/builds/228132933#L518)